# Can anybody explain this read-only exception to me?

Tags: perl, readonly

Below is my code (don't worry there's a USUW at the top of the module)

I'm testing if an array ref is readonly, and if that is the case then I'm copying it into another array ref. The tests show that the array is not read-only, yet when it runs, it fails with that error. ( For those of you not familiar with me or [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart::Comments)--those `###` are [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart::Comments).)

```
### readonly( $arg_ref ) : readonly( $arg_ref )
### readonly( @$arg_ref ) : readonly( @$arg_ref )
my @ro = map { readonly( $_ ) } @$arg_ref;
### @ro
if ( readonly $arg_ref ) {
    $arg_ref = [ @$arg_ref ];
}
return map { my $val = shift @$arg_ref;
             $_ => $val 
            } @_ 
            ;
```

This is the output I get:

```
### readonly( $arg_ref ) : 0
### readonly( @$arg_ref ) : 0

### @ro: [
###        0,
###        0,
###        0,
###        0,
###        0
###      ]
```

But here's the error:

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted at ....pm line 247.
```

(247 is:

```
return map { my $val = shift @$arg_ref;
```

)

Does anybody have any familiarity with this issue? We're running Perl 5.8.7. Any idea on how to address it?

Comment: Where is the `readonly` symbol coming from? I don't think the Readonly module provides one.

Comment: @Ether it's [`Scalar::Util::readonly`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util#readonly)

Comment: How is `$arg_ref` getting its value?

Comment: @gbacon: ultimately from DBI->fetchrow_arrayref but I thought Scalar::Util::readonly would catch it, and I would do a jit copy to continue on with the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the result of [Scalar::Util::readonly](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util) can be <strike>trusted</strike> used how you want to use it. Witness:

```
perl -MScalar::Util=readonly -MReadonly -wle'
    Readonly my $arg_ref => [ qw(a b c)];
    print readonly $arg_ref;
    $arg_ref = 1;'
```

prints:

```
0
 Modification of a read-only value attempted at -e line 1.
```

(Tested under perl5.8.8 with Readonly 1.03, Scalar::Util 1.23)

Comment: I just ran the test above on perl5.12.1 and got the same result. :(

Comment: That's because Readonly and readonly are different things.  :)  See my answer for why.

Comment: @Robert: good to know. This has probably confused more than a few people.

Comment: I don't like the "solution", but watching out for readonly's failures seems to be it. I coded a redo loop to address it--something I hadn't done since coding in *VB*!!

Answer (score 2):

If the reference from `DBI::fetchrow_arrayref` is coming back read-only, attempting to overwrite it won't help: the *reference* is read-only, not the thingie (*i.e.*, the array with column values).

Make your own copy right at the source if you need destructive updates, *e.g.*,

```
my $arg_ref = [ $sth->fetchrow_array ];
```

Comment: @Axeman But if `$arg_ref` may be read-only, destructive operations such as `shift` aren't suitable, which you've observed.

Comment: indeed and part of programming is solving problems. A queue is *transportable* a "list stream" isn't unless you want to cobble together a combination of list and current spot in the list. But that would never do more than a good old fashioned queue that you get for free with a Perl array. Now, I could *always* copy it, but a "performance and efficiency weenie" like myself gets hives thinking about not doing only what is needed.

Comment: ah, ya see, that's the copying that this p&e weenie doesn't want to do at the query object level, because it's fine if somebody just wants to read the row. What I did to solve this--although my curiosity continues-- is that I now pass a parameter to the query object method so that clients can let the process know that they want to do "something dumb" with them. But we can always code around something, I want to know why I can't anticipate it will need it--and answer that problem. Must be something in the XS layer of the Oracle DBD module. I should try to see it is `tied`!

Answer (score 1):

Readonly and readonly are different.  (Notice the capital R and lowercase r. ;-) )

See the [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util) documentation for why this is true:

> readonly SCALAR
>
> Returns true if SCALAR is readonly.
>
> ```
> sub foo { readonly($_[0]) }
> $readonly = foo($bar);              # false
> $readonly = foo(0);                 # true
> ```

This is more about aliases (such as those passed in via foreach loops or in `@_`, and not the Readonly module.

Comment: So is there any way of checking if a variable was declared Readonly with a capital R?

Comment: Both Readonly::XS and the XS implementation of readonly rely on the same flag (SvREADONLY), so they should be the same (if you're using the XS versions, which you should). I smell a bug here.

Comment: @Ether, IIUC, `ref(tied( A_VARIABLE )) =~ /^Readonly::/` should do the trick, and you'll want to fall back to checking `Scalar::Util::readonly` if that check is false.

Comment: @Leon, can you expand on that?  Readonly.pm 1.03 sure looks to me like it checks `$XSokay` (i.e., is `Readonly::XS` present?), setting SvREADONLY if so *but otherwise* doing a `tie` to a `Readonly::Foo` class that has no working mutators in the pure perl logic branches...

Comment: I've just posted an answer detailing what's going on. It's a Readonly bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have it figured out. Robert P was right, but he only got half of the answer: `Readonly` and `readonly` do different things though they should do the same thing, the fact that they don't is a bug. I'll try to explain what is going on.

`Readonly` has two implementations for scalars: one ([Readonly::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Readonly::XS)) that is based on the `SvREADONLY` flag and one (Readonly::Scalar) based on ties that emulates the `SvREADONLY` flag.

`readonly` also has two implementations, one in Perl (which does self assignment and checks if it throws an exception or not), and one in XS (again based on the `SvREADONLY` flag).

There are 4 possible combinations, and unfortunately the one that is most common (pure perl Readonly and XS readonly) is the only one that doesn't work as advertised.

Here's the crux: `sub Readonly::Readonly` actually doesn't use `Readonly::XS` at all, only `sub Readonly::Scalar` does. **This is probably a bug**. `readonly` *correctly* reports that the variable is not a readonly variable: its readonlyness is faked by a tie.

It's `Readonly` that's at fault here IMO, it should do the right thing when it can and document when it can't. Right now it's doing neither of those.

Comment: From my perspective, there's no issue with `Readonly`, we don't even have it installed in our environment. The only thing this concerns is `Scalar::Util::readonly`'s inability to tell me that a array reference an array reference is readonly until I try to shift on it.

Comment: Actually it seems that its not the array *reference* isn't readonly but the array it refers to. A subtle but important difference.

Comment: This behaviour definitely contradicts the documentation -- it says that when one has Readonly::XS installed, it is used in all cases for scalars (but not arrays and hashes). Bummer.  (So who's going to file a bug, or even better submit a patch?) :)

Comment: I've already written a patch, be the author hasn't replied to my email yet.